# GoogleSheets - How to A-Z Sort Data Pulled by (Filter(Importrange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a link to my sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113PRiJKxz_fIPmIoPID5e2IzrZF9ZptslX06JbIatDE/edit?usp=sharing

I am currently attempting to sort data pulled from another sheet into the one linked above by using filter(importrange.

What I have is a list of websites(Col2) with associated data points pulled in different adjacent columns. I have pulled a list of websites into this sheet using filter(importrange.

I have then pulled all associated data points (13 per website) from the other sheet also using filter(importrange, but making the criteria based upon matching the website within this new sheet to websites within the original list.

The idea is to pull all websites and corresponding data points that meet a certain criteria, in this case all websites that contain the ad network "Content.ad".

I have achieved this but now I am wondering how I will be able to sort this data in the new sheet where the data is being filtered into.

I would like to have the ability to sort the list of websites A-Z based upon the different data points, while having each column rearrange so that each data point remains with its associated website while being sorted.

For example if I want to sort the list from A-Z by Traffic Volume, I would like all data points to sort according to the position of their associate website.

Apologies if I have explained this inadequately.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google Sheets .

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that doesn't rely upon an external link.  This is so that the question and answer will still contribute something to the community even if the link is broken in the future.

Comment: I should also add that there is a way to do this but I'm not referencing your sheet in my answer :)